# Save created image on FTP?

Tags: python, image, ftp

I have created a generator of .tiff images for a school project, it works pretty well on my PC !

This generator is now on ftp server, and it's censed to generate the .tiff, and save it on ftp to be able to be downloaded.. 
But it doesn't work. I call my python script with functions php exec() or system() when users click on the specified button "generate" 
Do you know how I can save my img .tiff on the ftp server with my python script ?

Thank you for your answers, and sorry for my English, I'm French.

---

```
img = Image.fromarray(data, 'CMYK') #Make image from matrix 
ftp = FTP('wbe-site', 'Identifiant', 'Password') #it's changed in my  
code
etat = ftp.getwelcome()
print("Etat : ", etat)
f = open(img, 'rb')     # Open the image 
ftp.storbinary('STOR carte.tiff', f)  #Save file on FTP
f.close()                                   # Close the file
ftp.quit()
```

---

Answer (score 2):

If you use ftplib you can use this code:

```
import ftplib
session = ftplib.FTP('server.address.com','USERNAME','PASSWORD')
file = open('kitten.jpg','rb')                  # file to send
session.storbinary('STOR kitten.jpg', file)     # send the file
file.close()                                    # close file and FTP
session.quit()
```

You are opening an image, not giving the open function a string.

Comment: do you have ftplib imported?  Also what error are you getting?

Comment: Yes ftplib is imported ;)

Here you can see my error message :

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./generation.py", line 96, in <module>
    tiffEnCouleurs(fichier)    #function making the file
  File "./generation.py", line 86, in tiffEnCouleurs
    f = open(img, 'rb')    #opening file .tiff 
TypeError: coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, Image found

Comment: You are supposed to give that section a "string or buffer" as stated in the error.  In my example it opens a "string" (kitten.jpg).  So if you could save the image as something and then open it like in my example, it should work.

Comment: The problem is that I can't save my image on the server and open it, I can do that on a PC, but not on a server

Comment: Yeah because you aren't giving it a valid file to save.

Answer (score 0):

After exhausting answers over stack overflow and the internet, I finally figured this out. You gotta buff your array like img and pass the buffer to a file like IO, before posting it on ftp.

```
des_ftp = ftplib.FTP()
des_ftp.cwd(DES_DIR)
_, buffer = cv2.imencode('.JPG', img)
io_buf = io.BytesIO(buffer)

des_ftp.storbinary('STOR '+img_name, io_buf)
```

Works for me.